# I have a graph with Sales on the vertical Axis and the dates on the horizontal axis, but it repeats the dates

Tags: excel, excel-online

I have a graph with Sales on the vertical Axis and the dates on the horizontal axis, but it repeats the dates.

I would like for the date to only show it self once and then on the vertical axis show the acumulate sales for that date or week.

[image]

Im trying to show the sales per week on a bar graph.

Comment: Did you try it with pivot chart?

Comment: in Excel Online I belive you dont have the option to create a picot chart.
You ca only create a chart.

Comment: Well, if you could share some sample data and expected results with that. (you can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post data as a table in your post.

Comment: I was able to generate what I think you need online using a pivot table, than base a chart on the pivot table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFR9M.png